# Ajax POST returns 403

Tags: ajax

I am working on a handmade blog website.
In my own handmade admin panel i created a form to add/edit posts.
For the blog content (richtext) i am using https://richtexteditor.com/ .

I am not using a standard `<form>` element,but inputs with id tags.
then i have a button with onclick event which is calling a javascript procedure:

```
        
var article_id = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('article_id').value);
var article_h1 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('article_h1').value);//header 1
var article_h2 = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('article_h2').value);//short blog recap
var category = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('category').value);//numeric category ID
var author = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('author').value);
var blog_text = encodeURIComponent(editor1.getHTML()); //getting the HTML code from richtextedit element

 $.ajax({
 cache: false  ,  
    method: 'POST',
    
  dataType:"false",
data:{
    'article_id' : article_id,
    'article_h1' : article_h1,
    'article_h2' : article_h2,
    'author' : author,
    'category' : category,
    'blog_text' : blog_text
},
 url: "./save_article.php",
 success: function(return_value) {
  document.getElementById('article_id').value=return_value
 }
 });
}
```

the ajax call is successfull, when i have plain text, or nothing in the richtextedit element. When it has some formatted HTML data, the request is failing with 403 error.

Also i was playing around with some contenttypes, headers and datatypes based on StackOverflow discussions,but nothing helped.

I was looking around the Stackoverflow forums and i did the following "fixes" :

Updated my .htaccess file with the following:

```
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
<IfModule mod_security.c>
  SecFilterEngine Off
  SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Encode the content before sedning

Comment: so, Why is *your* "handmade" backend responding with a 403?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss : i am using encodeURIComponent , however it's only needed for the HTML code

Comment: @KevinB is it backend? it's just a simple urldecode($_POST['variables']) command. Do you think it's on the php side?

Comment: Well, your server is throwing the error due to the input it is receiving. Unless you just want to keep throwing darts at the wall, you need to know why it's throwing that error. Get some logging involved.

Comment: so i realized, it's happening only when i am trying to POST an image with dataurl if it helps.. Maybe some php setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the cause of the problem was the LiteSpeed web cache manager, that was against my POST requests. Once i flushed the LS cache, it works.